# Random number 0's or 1's

Tags: c#, random

I am looking to generate 0's or 1's only for each array like:

```
int[] x = new int [10];
```

I would like to generate 10 numbers either 0's or 1's and **should not all 0's**

It's only like this:

```
Random binaryrand = new Random(2);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What problems are you having in doing this, is it you don't know how to fill the array? or something else?

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess that you're using `new random` and not `random.Next`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [`Random.Next(Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) method like;

```
int[] x = new int[10];
Random r = new Random();

while (x.Any(item => item == 1) == false)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
         x[i] = r.Next(0, 2);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
}
```

Example output;

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/VOX0E0).

Remember, on `Random.Next(Int32, Int32)` method, lower bound is *inclusive* but upper bound is *exclusive*.

Comment: You missed one requirement, you must exclude arrays that haves all 0's. Throwing the first for loop in a `while(x.Any(item => item == 1) == false)` would fix that.

Comment: thank you very much, I would like to fill the array either 0's or 1's without all 0's in case

Comment: What do you mean of this? I don't like to get an array of all 0's in case. fill the array either 1's or 0's without all 0's.

Comment: Yamur - wrap it in a `while(!list.Any(x => x == 1))` if you really must, **Edit** just realise thats what scott meant ^.^

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much all of you :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain OP doesn't required it but anyway, updated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes he does say it is required in fact it is **bold text** in his original question. *"I would like to generate 10 numbers either 0's or 1's and **should not all 0's**"*

Answer (score 2):

Your call

```
Random binaryrand = new Random(2);
```

creates a Random generator with `seed=2`, it will produce the same sequence of numbers each time you run this code. The `2` has nothing to do with the range of the generated numbers.

Use

```
 Random binaryrand = new Random();  // auto seed

 ...

    int x = binaryrand.Next(2);
```

Comment: +1, but I'd edit the answer inviting to call the parameterless constructor.

Comment: Agreed, avoids confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This also ensures that not all are 0

```
Random binaryrand = new Random();
List<int> l = new List<int>();

while (l.Find(x => x == 1) != 1)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       l.Add(binaryrand.Next(0, 2));
   }
 }
```

Comment: Great, That is for list :)

Comment: That list will be the same on each run of the program.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is absolutly right, you need to drop the seed. See my edits

Comment: @Yamur Why this answer selected? Hank's and mine are better answer in my opinion..

Comment: @Soner Gönul. Actually, I've tried the two solution and I found your suggestion is easier for this reason today I select your question. Can I have your email address for more discussion. I cann't post question any more :(.